# Cucumber/Phantomjs not loading https - so how do I change the phantom settings?

Tags: ruby, https, phantomjs, cucumber

I'm using phantomjs as my browser to run my ruby cucumber scripts.

When I try and run some https-based scripts, Chrome, Firefox, etc all pass but phantomjs fails.

I've seen where I can change the phantomjs settings to `--ssl-protocol=any` for example, or `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes`.  But where do I set these when using Cucumber?

I (naively) thought I could just add it to the end of the cucumber command (`cucumber ./features/ABC-1234.feature -p phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes etc, etc`), but this obviously didn't work.

I've tried adding it to the cucumber hook file, but again to no avail.

Comment: Ok, so I'm pretty certain that this command line setting (for example, --ignore-ssl-errors=yes) needs to be added into the env.rb file of my cucumber project. But what I don't know is how to add this. I've seen an example for Capybara, but I'm not using Capybara (I'm using Selenium and Phantom).

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to initiate phantomjs driver with selenium ?

Comment: I just have this in my Cucumber env.rb file;  `@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for ENV['BROWSER'].to_sym`  and this in my cucumber.yml file;  `phantomjs: BROWSER=phantomjs`  then pass the browser type using the Cucumber profile (-p phantomjs).  Thanks.